# SSRS Shared Datasets

Tags: ssrs-2008

In SSRS(2008 specifically), do shared datasets hold the same data across all reports in the same project(effectively working as global variables), or just hold a dataset schema that can be referenced by all the reports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes shared datasets hold the same data across all reports.

You can try [**this**](http://joegilldotcom.blogspot.com/2010/07/reporting-services-shared-datasets.html) link to understand further usage.